# With whose wand did Harry fight Voldemort after his wand was broken?

Tags: harry-potter

In 7th movie, Harry's wand was broken when he was in Godric's Hollow, then we saw Ron bringing him another one. Is this the one that he fought Voldemort with? Did he fight him with Draco's wand? How did he fight Voldemort?

Comment: He fought with Draco's wand, which is *a very big part of it*. I'd advise you to read the books.

Answer (score 10):

**He fought at the battle with Draco's wand.**

He got Draco's wand while fighting him at Malfoy Manor, and since he had taken it from Draco, it would work better than a wand he didn't take himself from its owner. Harry of course didn't have time to buy a new wand, so he kept using Draco's wand and would have used it in the battle against the Dark Lord as well.

> "Hawthorn and unicorn hair. Ten inches precisely. Reasonably springy. This was the wand of Draco Malfoy."
>
> "Was?" repeated Harry. "Isn't it still his?"
>
> "Perhaps not. If you took it –"
>
> "– I did –"
>
> "– then it may be yours. Of course, the manner of taking matters. Much also depends upon the wand itself. In general, however, where a wand has been won, its allegiance will change." <sub><sup>- *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 24 ("The Wandmaker")*</sup></sub>

Harry tells the Dark Lord, in part of a speech about Harry being the master of the Elder Wand, that the wand in his hand is Draco's.

> “But you’re too late,’ said Harry. ‘You’ve missed your chance. I got there first. I overpowered Draco weeks ago. I took this wand from him.’
> Harry twitched the hawthorn wand, and he felt the eyes of everyone in the Hall upon it.” <sub><sup>- *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 36 (The Flaw in the Plan)*</sup></sub>

Harry is then shown to actually be using Draco's wand, proving conclusively that it's the wand he used against the Dark Lord.

> “Harry heard the high voice shriek as he, too, yelled his best hope to the heavens, pointing Draco’s wand:
>
> ‘Avada Kedavra!’
>
> ‘Expelliarmus!” <sub><sup>- *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 36 (The Flaw in the Plan)*</sup></sub>

**Before that, he had borrowed Hermione's, then used one Ron got from a Snatcher.**

When Harry's wand first broke there were no spare wands available, so if he needed to use a wand he had to borrow Hermione's.

> "Well,"’ he said, in a falsely matter-of-fact voice, "well, I'll just borrow yours for now, then. While I keep watch."
> Her face glazed with tears, Hermione handed over her wand, and he left her sitting beside his bed, desiring nothing more than to get away from her." <sub><sup>- *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 17 ("Bathilda's Secret")*</sup></sub>

When Ron came back though, he had managed to get the wand of one of the Snatchers who tried to capture him, and Harry used that for a while.

> "Then two of them got into a fight and while the others were distracted I managed to hit the one holding me in the stomach, grabbed his wand, Disarmed the bloke holding mine and Disapparated." <sub><sup>- *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 19 ("The Silver Doe")*</sup></sub>

Comment: IIRC, in the battle Harry says something like 'I took this wand from Draco Malfoy' - if I'm correct, that would be a good addition.